# Navigation component: unexpected element <nav-graph> found in presentation module

Tags: android, androidx

Android Studio 3.5 and Navigation Components 2.1.0 
Clean arch with app, presentation, domain, data modules

presentation/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme">
        <activity android:name=".feature.base.view.HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_login" />
        </activity>
    ...
```

**Gradle assemble error**
  Execution failed for task ':presentation:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   Android resource linking failed
>            /Users/x/presentation/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-71: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

I can't run the app because of `Default Activity not found`, but if I remove `<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_login" />` it works.
Any idea why I can't define my AndroidManifest inside presentation module?

Opened issue on
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140856013

Comment: the `nav-graph` doesn't stay there

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Yes, according documentation and for example this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/NavigationBasicSample/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: are you handling deep links?

Comment: yes. I'm handling deeplinks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140856013
"The fix for this will be in 3.7 Canary 2 and 3.6 Beta 2"